# How to plot a 3D graph in X-Y-color dimensions in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, 3d

I've got a scalar function of two variables that I want to plot. Using `surf` and rotating the 3D plot so that it is seen directly from above works, but it feels like I'm wasting resources that way. I don't want the 3D parts.

Is there a Matlab function for what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes,
The function `imagesc` will do that